# Java: CardLayout switching between cards

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I've got class 'Frame' which extends `JFrame` and separetad `JPanels`: `MainMenu` and `SinglePanel`
I am using `CardLayout`, but I've got problem when switching back to panels using  `buttonSingle` and `powrot` buttons. So my question is how can I change/swap between cards using these buttons?

My `Frame` class:

```
    public class Frame extends JFrame{

    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    final MainMenu menuPanel = new MainMenu();
    final SinglePanel singlePanel = new SinglePanel();

    public Frame(){

        setLayout(cl);
        add(menuPanel,"menu");
        add(singlePanel,"single");


        setSize(200, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setEnabled(true);
        swapView("menu");

    }

    public void swapView(String view){
        cl.show(getContentPane(),view);
    } 
}
```

my `MainMenu` class:

```
public class MainMenu extends JPanel{


    public MainMenu(){


        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this , BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        JButton buttonSingle = new JButton("Single");     
        buttonSingle.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        buttonSingle.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        add(buttonSingle);
        add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        JButton buttonMulti = new JButton("Multiplayer"); 
        buttonMulti.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        buttonMulti.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });
        add(buttonMulti);
        add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
        JButton buttonExit = new JButton("Wyjście");  
        buttonExit.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        buttonExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }});
            add(buttonExit);
            add(Box.createVerticalGlue());                        
        }
    }
```

my `SinglePanel` class

```
public class SinglePanel extends JPanel{

    SinglePanel(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JButton powrot = new JButton("Wróć do menu");        
        powrot.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        add(powrot);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here      

        /*MainMenu mM = new MainMenu();*/

        Frame f = new Frame();
    }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a reference to the `CardLayout` of the `JFrame` inside your panel classes. What you can do is pass the `Frame` to the `JPanel` classes as reference, then you can use the `CardLayout` of the `Frame` in those classes to `show` or `next` etc. Something like

```
public class MainMenu {
    private CardLayout layout;
    private Frame frame;

    public MainMenu(final Frame frame) {
         this.frame = frame;
         this.layout = (CardLayout)frame.getLayout();

         JButton buttonSingle = new JButton("Single");     
         buttonSingle.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
         buttonSingle.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 layout.show(frame, "single");
             }
         });
    }
}
```

When you create the `MainPanel`, you need to pass `Frame.this` to it, referencing the current `Frame`

```
MainMenu menuPanel = new MainMenu(Frame.this);
```

---

**EDIT**

I just noticed your `swapView` method. So instead of use the `CardLayout` directly in the panel class, you can actually just call `swapView` in the `actionPerformed`

```
frame.swapView("single");
```

Or better yet, as to not expose the `Frame` class, you can have the `Frame` class implement an `interface` say `SwapInterface` that has a method `swapView` you need to override. And pass the `SwapInterface` to the panel classes. Something like

```
public interface SwapInterface {
    public void swapView(String view);
}

public Frame extends JFrame implements SwapInterface {
    MainMenu mainPanel = new MainMenu(Frame.this);
    ....
    @Override
    public void swapView(String view) {
        cl.show(getContentPane(), view);
    }
}

public class MainMenu extends JPanel {
    private SwapInterface swap;

    public MainMenu(SwapInterface swap) {
        this.swap = swap;
        ...
        public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent e) {
            swap.swapView("single");
        }

    }
}
```

---

**Side Note**

As HovercraftFullOfEels pointed out in his comment, you should make use of String contants for the String card values so there's no mistakes. Something like

```
private static final String SINGLE_CARD = "single";
```

Then in places where you use `"single"`, use `SINGLE_CARD` instead

Comment: I've seen this method of using an interface to swap the pages several times now. Is this a pattern or is there a name for it, so I can read more about it somewhere? Because I am not sure in which order what is used, why I need an instance(?) of `SwapInterface` in the `MainMenu`-class etc.