# How to Switch between Panels in CardLayout from ActionListeners in external classes

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, cardlayout

I have a cardLayout in the main class that the Gui classes are added to layout via panels and when the Room1Button is pressed how would it switch the card in the main method to the Gui2 card

is this the best way to go about this any help would be apreatiated

Main Method

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  class Main
  {

CardLayout cl=new CardLayout();
GridBagConstraints gb=new GridBagConstraints();
JFrame frame=new JFrame("Frame");
JPanel panel =new JPanel();


Gui1 g1= Gui1();
Gui2 g2= Gui2();


public Main()
{
   panel.setLayout(cl);
   panel.add(g1, "1");
   panel.add(g2, "2");

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    cl.show(panel,"1");

    //how would the actionlistner in the Gui1 class switch the layout to "2"

    cl.show(panel, "2");


}


public static void main(String[]param)
{
    new Main();


}


}
```

The gui1 class

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.util.*;


 public class Gui1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{


private JButton room1Button;

JPanel panel=new JPanel();

{



    setSize(1000,1000);

    panel.setVisible(true);

    room1Button=new JButton("Go the next Panel");

    this.setVisible(true);
    room1Button.addActionListener(this);
    add(room1Button);


}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource()==room1Button){
       Window w = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(R0.this);
       w.setVisible(false);

    }

}
}
```

The Gui2 class

```
 public class Gui2 extends JPanel implements Actionlistener
 {
        // some code

 }
```

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593162/java-cardlayout-switching-between-cards

Comment: this particular problem doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ActionEvent will contain the source object that generated the event. In this case the JButton. So generic code for the ActionListener in your GUI1 class would be something like:

```
JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
JPanel buttonPanel = (JPanel)button.getParent();
JPanel cardLayoutPanel = (JPanel)buttonPanel.getParent();
CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)cardLayoutPanel.getLayout();
layout.show(cardLayoutPanel, "2");
```

Comment: so the parent in this example is referring to the panel made in the main class

Comment: There are two parent panels in this example. The first is the panel that contains the button. The second is the panel using the CardLayout.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps.

```
package cardlayoutsample;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CardLayoutSample {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("CardLayout Demo");
    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelFirst = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelSecond = new JPanel();
    JButton btnOne = new JButton("Switch");
    JButton btnTwo = new JButton("Back");

    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

    public CardLayoutSample(){
        panelCont.setLayout(cl);

        panelFirst.add(btnOne);
        panelSecond.add(btnTwo);
        panelFirst.setBackground(Color.red);
        panelSecond.setBackground(Color.blue);

        panelCont.add(panelFirst,"1");
        panelCont.add(panelSecond,"2");
        cl.show(panelCont, "1");

        btnOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            cl.show(panelCont, "2");
        }
    });

        btnTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            cl.show(panelCont, "1");
        }
    }); 

        frame.add(panelCont);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardLayoutSample a = new CardLayoutSample();
    }
}
```

Try to play this button you can see it's switching the panels when you clicked the buttons.

Syntax for ActionListener

```
Component.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
@Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  //do this
 }
});
```

Example

```
LogoutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
@Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   System.exit(0);
 }
  });
```

Comment: The Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) has demo code which shows how to swap panels when all the code is defined in the same class. The tutorial code would be a better example because is also shows how to better structure the code so the GUI is created on the EDT. However neither the tutorial or this code example answer the question. The OP is wondering how to do this when the panels are defined in separate classes, not in the main class so you don't have direct access to the CardLayout..

Comment: You saved me lots of time, thank you bro.