# how to display panel on click of button on different panel in another panel present in jframe in netbean java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have one jframe called mainframe in which their is a panel called dpanel and two    separate panels p1 and p2 created in netbeans. In panel p1 their is a button and click on this button I want to display panel p2 on dpanel in mainframe.

Comment: post your tried code.

Comment: button in p1 , dpanel is in jframe mainframe , want to display p2 in dpanel on click of button in p1 code i used mainframe.dpanel.add(p2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a `CardLayout` to swap panels.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and a working example where all the panels are defined in the same class.

For an example where the child panels of the CardLayout are defined in separated classs check out: [How to Switch between Panels in CardLayout from ActionListeners in external classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283545/how-to-switch-between-panels-in-cardlayout-from-actionlisteners-in-external-clas/36287900#comment60201988_36287900)

Comment: @RobinSinha, then what is the problem? You have been given solutions for two different approaches.

Comment: thank you so much problem is solved by your link given